# Can't see my H2 database in Web Console

Tags: java, h2

I created a H2 database with my code with this URL:

> jdbc:h2:C:/data/fixed.db

My code can create tables, perform queries. If I open the file manually, I can successfully see its content and view the create queries etc

However, when I try to use H2 console with the web interface, I can't see the database. Instead, the web console create **another** empty database located here `C:/data/fixed.db.mv.db`. I just can't load my database.

What am I missing ?

**EDIT**

My code uses H2 **1.3.175**
The web console H2 **1.4.178**

Comment: Does the file name need the `.db` extension?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Even without the `.db` extension I got the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem...

Since 1.4.x, H2 uses MV_STORE (see SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23807061/363573) and Thomas Mueller comment).
Apparently, the web console tries to append automatically a `.mv.db` extension. Even if there is already a file with the `h2.db` extension.

So , I upgrade the H2 version of my code from 1.3.175 to 1.4.178 and finally, I can see my data...

**EDIT**
Here is an alternative solution proposed by [@devdanke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891203/devdanke):

> You must manually tell your H2 1.4.x not to use MV_Store: ";mv_store=false". What a hassle.

For example, you would end with a code similar to:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( //
    "jdbc:h2:file:C:\\my\\java\\projects\\test;mv_store=false" //
);
```

Comment: Many 3rd party database tools use H2 1.3.x because it's the stable version.  Yet H2 1.4.x defaults to using the "beta", "experimental" MV_Store storage engine, which H2 1.3.x can't read.  Because of H2's unfortunate default, you must manually tell your H2 1.4.x not to use MV_Store:   ";mv_store=false".  What a hassle.

Comment: @devdanke your comment alone solved my problem, which was similar to the OP but until now I wasn't being able to solve it. Thanks a lot! ";mv_store=false" does the trick!

Comment: Reading my comment a few years later, I regret the tone.  I was annoyed by the H2 config default.  But, more importantly I am thankful to Thomas Müller, his excellent H2 DB, and that he gives it to us for free.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think **.db** is required in `jdbc:h2:C:/data/fixed.db`

I used this two lines and it worked fine for me

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:G:\\projects\\test;MODE=MySQL;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/test.sql'\\;");
```

My code just created a db file-format by the name *test.mv.db*