# Not able to view H2 database tables and values created in java

Tags: database, h2

I am using h2-1.4.196.The JDBC URL is given as jdbc:h2:/home/Abc/test
and DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:h2:file:/home/Abc/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MV_STORE=FALSE" 
to connect to the database but I am not able to see the tables.

The same issue was given in [Can't see my H2 database in Web Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24401635/8305811)
However the code and console uses the same versions. Giving ;MV_STORE=FALSE didn't help. Is there anything else to be done?

Comment: What is `JDBC URL` and `DB_CONNECTION` where are you using them? If you don't see the tables how do you know that they are in the database?

Comment: DB_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver"  DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:h2:file:/home/Annie.Alfred/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE"

Comment: Two files are created test.trace.db and test.h2.db and the code works well without giving error. if I create table with same name it gives an exception saying that table already exists. So its like creating and insertion is done  but cannot see where it is.

Comment: Where and what do you want to 'see'? You can add rows to it with `INSERT` or  get rows from it with `SELECT`.

Comment: I found the tables created and the data inserted. Its taking some time to reflect in the console. Its not having immediate effect in the database console.

Comment: Alright, good to know. Do you have an [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question to ask?