# SpringBoot H2 setup issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

Configuration Details

1. Spring: 2.6
2. IDE: Intellij
3. Java 11

I have created a spring boot application with plugins as

1. Spring Web
2. H2 Database

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring5webapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring5webapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:AS;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=true
```

**commandLineRunner**

```
@Component
public class BootStrapData implements CommandLineRunner {


    private final AuthorRepository authorRepository;
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;
    private final PublisherRepository publisherRepository;

    public BootStrapData(AuthorRepository authorRepository, BookRepository bookRepository,
                         PublisherRepository publisherRepository) {
        this.authorRepository = authorRepository;
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
        this.publisherRepository = publisherRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Author eric = new Author("Eric", "Evans");
        authorRepository.save(eric);
        System.out.println("Started in bootstrap");
        System.out.println("Number of Authors " + authorRepository.count());

    }
}
```

**authorRepository.java**

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {

}
```

**Author.java (Pojo)**

```
package guru.springframework.spring5webapp.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    public Author() {
    }

    public Author(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Set<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Author{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", books=" + books +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Author author = (Author) o;

        return id != null ? id.equals(author.id) : author.id == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

When I am starting the application and go to http://localhost:8080/h2-console, I see a JDBC Url of
jdbc:h2:~/test instead of jdbc:h2:mem:AS. Logging in the console I do not see the Author table.

I have seen the content of following posts in stackoverflow but of no use

1. [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763747/h2-in-memory-database-table-not-found)
2. [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219282/not-able-to-view-h2-database-tables-and-values-created-in-java)

My github project is at [here](https://github.com/Animesh420/spring5webapp) it has further more interaction of Pojos
What is the mistake in the project?

Comment: You can enter the right URL (`jdbc:h2:mem:AS;`) on the H2 console login screen and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes this is the right approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by user g00glen00b in comments, one has to explicitly enter the URL in the H2 console.