# How to access in memory h2 database of one spring boot application from another spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, h2

In my project, i have created 3 spring boot application. First spring boot application has h2 embedded database. Now i want to access this database from my 2nd and 3rd spring boot application directly without writing any services to get this data. So can anyone tell me how can i achieve this?

Comment: Raj, don't forget to accept an answer that helped you...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can setup H2 Server as Spring Bean.

First edit pom.xml - delete `<scope>runtime</scope>` from h2 dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then add H2 server bean to `SpringBootApplication` or `Configuration` class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * Start internal H2 server so we can query the DB from IDE
     *
     * @return H2 Server instance
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
    }
}
```

Last - edit `application.properties` - set the name of the database:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:dbname
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Then you can connect to this H2 Server **from outside** (e.g. to your application with H2 DB) using this connection:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:dbname
```

As a bonus using this url you can connect to the database of your app **right from your IDE**.

**UPDATE**

There is a chance of getting an error when trying to connect to the H2 for Spring Boot app of 1.5.x version. In this case just change a version of H2 to previous one, for example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.193</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you need to run several apps with H2 simultaneously on the same host you should set the different H2 ports on them in `Server.createTcpServer` mothod, for example: 9092, 9093, etc..

```java
// First App
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
    return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
}

// Second App
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
    return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9093");
}
```

Then you can connect to the H2 DB of these apps with following urls:

```
App1 H2: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:dbname
App2 H2: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9093/mem:dbname
```

Comment: @Salman `Server` is the class of the `org.h2.tools` package from `com.h2database:h2` artifact - see dependency. And don't forget to remove `<scope>runtime</scope>` from it.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, in the configuration file of other applications which you try to connect from, you should set `spring.datasource.url` to `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:dbname`

Comment: @sedooe Off cause. I wrote that - see last lines of the answer. Or you mean something different?..

Comment: ah sorry, didn't see that line :)

Comment: I followed the above instructions but I get errors. Should different spring boot applications be configured & started with different jdbc urls? I started the first application with jdbc:h2:mem:AZ as the url while the second with jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:AZ keeping the above bean configuration same for both. The second application fails to start with error as "Exception opening port "9092" (port may be in use)". Could you please document the config required by two applications separately? Thanks !

Comment: @Cepr0 - I wasn't asking of running two h2 databases on the same machine. My question is to understand the config of starting two application that refer to a common h2 database. thanks!

Comment: @AndyDufresne You need only the first app to have a database, and the second app to connect to the the first app db? In this case you should setup `h2Server` bean only in the first app. First app should connect to own db with url `jdbc:h2:mem:dbname`, and second app should connect to the db with url `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:dbname`.

Comment: @Cepr0 - yes, I did exactly that but my second app fails with "Exception opening port "9092" (port may be in use), cause: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind" [90061-192]". Note that I have removed the bean configuration for the second app. Spring boot version is 1.3.6. One thing I observed is - after second app fails with the above error, connecting to the database via h2-console also fails which works before starting the second app.

Comment: @AndyDufresne It's strange... What if you change the server port in the first app h2Server bean to 9093?..

Comment: @Cepr0 - same error. For reference i am starting two instances of this application - https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-spring-boot-jpa-example but changing the configuration for both the runs.

Comment: @AndyDufresne please check my [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/one-h2-two-app) - all works as expected: first start FirstApplication (serves 9092), then start SecondApplication (works with 9092).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164406/discussion-between-andy-dufresne-and-cepr0).

Comment: One important difference i noticed is that the two apps in your commit are separate maven projects. I have been starting two applications by executing two java classes inside the same maven project though configured differently by different properties files

Comment: Also for me it is important that I run the application through two java classes instead of separate java projects since I want to mimic two app servers serving one web application. I do not think though that these could be the root cause of the problem

Comment: Thank you, but now spring boot ignores my data.sql on startup

Comment: It works but data.sql doesnt add my test data?

Comment: You rock!.. Thanks a lot for these wonderful explanations, voted up ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can run `H2` in the server mode.

```
import org.h2.tools.Server;
...
// start the TCP Server
server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers").start();
...
// stop the TCP Server
server.stop();

Usage: java org.h2.tools.Server 
When running without options, -tcp, -web, -browser and -pg are started.
Options are case sensitive. Supported options are:
[-help] or [-?]         Print the list of options
[-web]                  Start the web server with the H2 Console
[-webAllowOthers]       Allow other computers to connect - see below
[-webDaemon]            Use a daemon thread
[-webPort ]       The port (default: 8082)
[-webSSL]               Use encrypted (HTTPS) connections
[-browser]              Start a browser connecting to the web server
[-tcp]                  Start the TCP server
[-tcpAllowOthers]       Allow other computers to connect - see below
[-tcpDaemon]            Use a daemon thread
[-tcpPort ]       The port (default: 9092)
[-tcpSSL]               Use encrypted (SSL) connections
[-tcpPassword ]    The password for shutting down a TCP server
[-tcpShutdown ""]  Stop the TCP server; example: tcp://localhost
[-tcpShutdownForce]     Do not wait until all connections are closed
[-pg]                   Start the PG server
[-pgAllowOthers]        Allow other computers to connect - see below
[-pgDaemon]             Use a daemon thread
[-pgPort ]        The port (default: 5435)
[-properties ""]   Server properties (default: ~, disable: null)
[-baseDir ]        The base directory for H2 databases (all servers)
[-ifExists]             Only existing databases may be opened (all servers)
[-trace]                Print additional trace information (all servers)
The options -xAllowOthers are potentially risky.
For details, see Advanced Topics / Protection against Remote Access.
See also http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html
```

[How to use h2 as a server](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server)

[Similar question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875524/how-do-you-connect-to-h2-as-a-remote-database-instead-of-embedded-mode-using-spr)

[Similar question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503079/start-the-h2-database-in-server-mode-via-spring)