# AnnotationException: MappedBy reference an unknown target entity property - mapping an inherited class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have such entities with inheritance

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class PostEntity {
    ...
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
        private UserEntity author;
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "answers")
    public class AnswerEntity extends PostEntity {}

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class UserEntity {
    ...
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<AnswerEntity> answers;
    }
```

during compilation, he throws me away

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.example.demo.jpa.entity.AnswerEntity.author in com.example.demo.jpa.entity.UserEntity.answers
```

I do not know why he does not see the `author` field during mapping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property with annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483712/mappedby-reference-an-unknown-target-entity-property-with-annotation)

Comment: No. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: During *compilation*?

Comment: Can you try making PostEntity abstract?

Comment: Have you tried moving the relationship to the child class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported by JPA, at least not by Hibernate. You can either have:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private List<PostEntity> answers;
```

Or move `UserEntity author` field to AnswerEntity.