# View data of H2 database during @DataJpaTest cases

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa, h2, embedded-database

I am learning spring-boot test and find [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing),

> 4.Integration Testing with @DataJpaTest

How can I view the content of h2 database using the info below by configuring client tool such as intellij-idea's Tool > Database.

Or is there any better way to peek those information.

`INFO 11276 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:094de3b8-72c0-4740-bdf6-5ae1a36ad9f4;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'`

Comment: see my how-to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276769

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about IntelliJ (because I love to use Eclipse), but in general you could access the h2 database like shown in [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/integrate-h2-database-in-your-spring-boot-applicat).

A small remaining obstacle in your case is that Spring Boot in combination with `@DataJpaTest` is initiating the database at the beginning of the tests and discards it after the tests complete. So there is "not really much time" to take a look into the database.

And depending on transactions, the flushing strategy and / or your manual flushing ([EntityManager.flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush--)) it's not guaranteed to see all changes of your domain objects during the tests.