# Spring Boot in memory database not accessible from other tools

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to access an in memory H2 database from the intellij console. I'm using spring boot to configure everything. The connection string is: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb

When I connect to the database using intellij I can't see or query the tables. I can run a create table command to get it but that is it. Here is an image of that config:

[image]

The result of a SHOW TABLES query returns nothing.

Why can't I connect to this database?

Comment: Why did you decide that your app doesn't run your schema?

Comment: I ran your code and its working. I would suggest to enable the h2 console in your properties file:

`spring.h2.console.enabled=true`
`spring.h2.console.path=/console`

That way you can query your db from your browser (*http://your_path/console*).

Comment: It's just from you log: `Executing SQL script from class path resource [schema-h2.sql]`

Comment: Don't use h2-console, use direct access to DB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276769

Comment: And don't forget to upvote the answer if it will help you ;)

Comment: @Cepr0 just updated my question with more details that are hopefully helpful.

Comment: Have you completed all the steps from my [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276769)? (I don't see it in your [repo](https://github.com/tschiman/water-meter)). First comment out all settings in your `app..properties` and set ones from how-to, then check again...

Comment: Ofcourse you cannot see it... It is an in-memory database and is only available to the application. You are basically starting a new db from IntelliJ. You either have to start H2 in server mode and connect to it or use a file based URI instead of in-memory.

Comment: Was out of town for a bit @M.Deinum you are correct. The in memory database is isolated to the running spring boot app. I cannot see it from intellij as when I create that db connection I create a new db. I've added some unit tests that confirm the database is there and operating.

Comment: @M.Deinum if you want to answer the edited question I will award your comment as the answer. I think it is important to indicate somwhere that the in memory connection string produces an isolated db that is not accessible elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using an in-memory database like H2 or HSQLDB that in-memory instance is only accessible from the application.

If you want to have a shared database (so that you can see what is inside it) you have to start it in [server mode][2] or use a file based mode instead (`jdbc:h2:~/your-db`).

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @m-deinum is generally right in that it's only available for the application by default. If you want to access the in-mem instance  from outside, you'll have to either:

- [expose it through spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256295/how-to-access-in-memory-h2-database-of-one-spring-boot-application-from-another/43276769#43276769) and use tcp connection string or
- [enable the h2 console](https://medium.com/@harittweets/how-to-connect-to-h2-database-during-development-testing-using-spring-boot-44bbb287570) and use that for login or
- enable [spring-boot dev tools](https://medium.com/@harittweets/how-to-connect-to-h2-database-during-development-testing-using-spring-boot-44bbb287570#fb00) and use its facilities to examine the db

And ensure the application is running. Otherwise you'd just be creating another in-mem instance.