# Default url and credentials for H2DB?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, h2db

I have added H2DB in my springBoot application for unit testing purpose.

In application-test.properties I just added:

spring.datasource.name = h2db

spring.h2.console.enabled = true

Its working fine, saving the values.

But how it is working and how can I browse this DB?

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Default properties for H2 in Spring Boot application are:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

So it's not necessary to add them to your `application.properties` - Spring Boot create this DB itself.

---

If you want to get access to your H2 DB right from your IDE you have to make [this setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276769/).

Comment: I have one more question on this, if I am running my local service then I can access it through its console but in case of unit testing how to use H2 console. In case of unit testing local server is not running.

Comment: @Sharad Don't forget to accept/upvote ALL answers that helped you )))

Comment: @Sharad don't use h2-console, use your IDE (SQL IDE). But when you run test - you cannot get access to H2DB ((