# Accessing H2 embedded database in something other than the web console?

Tags: java, spring, h2

I open up an embedded database for test and can access through the browser, similar to PHPMyAdmin. I'm typing in the JDBC URL into IntelliJ to establish a connection to the database with the credentials in my application.properties, but getting a connection failure.

#### Properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

My question is, what is the correct way to establish a connection to an embedded database outside of the web console?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [starting the TCP server](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html?highlight=TCP%20server&search=TCP%20server#firstFound) which could handle the request from JDBC client.

For spring boot, the solution could be found in other questions. For example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276769