# H2 Console Servlet does not display tables

Tags: java, database, h2

I'm having problem with my H2 console servlet, for some reason it does not display the my applications tables on the left side. Everything else works fine, I can run my SQls with no problem, but for some reason the tables are not being displayed on the left menu.

I have take a look on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806471/why-is-my-embedded-h2-program-writing-to-a-mv-db-file) but it didn't work (I tried with h2 1.4.191).

> H2 Configuration

- Version: 1.3.175
- Servlet Configuration:

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>webAllowOthers</param-name>
          <param-value></param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>trace</param-name>
          <param-value></param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/db/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

> Erros printed on browser console

It is failing to load the "tree.js"

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: setNode is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: writeTree is not defined
```

> Console Print

[image: Console Print]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: I copied the missing .js from the jar to my project in the path the console expected, now the tables are being displayed with no problem. But I still don't understand why I have that missing .js problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it likes the UI problem (some JS files are not executed)... not Servlet one. Specify you browser please in question and try another one.

If you use Chrome - try to debug via Chrome Developer Tool (F12)

Also try to restart H2 DB as Administrator.. maybe you don't have permissions for some files on you disk

Comment: Good tip! I did not think it could be a front-end problem. Just added the erros I found on console.

Comment: I'm using google chrome v43 and also tested on firefox 39

Comment: Try to restart h2 DB with Administrator rights.. maybe you don't have permissions for some files on you disk

Comment: Hi @kostyan_SV, I tried the admin rights (If that was the problem, I don't beleave the console would even open in the first place =/). Still dont work

Comment: I see.. very strange behaviour :)